# WebView2 Screen Share Position and Change Style

Tags: screen, share, webview2

Loading webview2 using WPF application。The shared screen window is fixed in the middle, hoping to change its position and change the window style。How to achieve？Can tab items be hidden in the window？

I am looking forward to customizing the UI, customizing the position of pop-up windows, and being able to hide tabs,